# Which ports does Ignite Server listens to

Tags: ignite

following is part of my configuration file that is passed to the Ignite.start(configuration_file).

I have thought that Ignite server will pick up a port from the port ranges(here is `37500..37509` in the configuration file).

But when I netstat the ports, it looks that these ports are never used?

I have two questions:
1. What are these port range used for? Aren't they used for the ports that the Ignite server will bind and listen to?
2. If the port above is not used for server to listen to?　Then how can I know or change the ports?

```
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">


        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>127.0.0.1:37500..37509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addresses provided in IP finder are the once node will try to connect to, not the ones it will listen to.

To change the port to bind to you should use `localPort` and `localPortRange` property. Fo the range mentioned in your example they should be set to `37500` and `10` respectively. Default values are `47500` and `100`.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin. I understood, but still  one more  question:  The port range(37500..37509) that i mentioned in the example is used for the server to connect to? Then, which process will listen on these ports or one of the range(37500..37509) , I didn't find that these ports are listened on through netstat, then the server will simply failed to connect?

Comment: Yes, for node to start, it has to be able to connect to one of the addresses provided by IP finder. If it can't connect to any of them, but binds itself to one of them, it will be started as the first node in topology. In all other cases it will fail to start.